# SPARQL Filter by distance

Tags: geolocation, location, sparql, virtuoso, geosparql

Given some Buildings with their respective locations (lat and long), how can I get only the ones within certain distance?

Let's say I have an individual `building0` located in an specific place.

```
ont1:building0 rdf:type ont1:Building 
ont1:building0 pos:lat 43.22 
ont1:building0 pos:lon -6.45
```

And I want to retrieve all the other buildings closer to 10km.

Does SPARQL allow to query this somehow?? Or at least show what the distance to other buildings is??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Support for geospatial queries depends on the used triple store. Some triple stores do support GeoSPARQL while others also provide built-in functions.

Comment: Since you've added that Virtuoso is your storage engine, [this page will be helpful](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtGeoSPARQLEnhancementDocs).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @TallTed . According to the page you provided, Virtuoso 7.1supports GeoSpatial features. What about lower versions? Is there any way of adding some kind of module that helps in this matter?

Comment: Upgrading to current Virtuoso (7.2.4.2+), which includes the GeoSpatial features, is strongly recommended for all users of all prior versions of Virtuoso. Back-porting GeoSpatial features to older 7.x or 6.x (last updated 2013-12-10) _might_ be possible, but this would be a [fee-for-service Custom Development project](https://ps.openlinksw.com/consultancy/).

Comment: I currently have Virtuoso version 06.01.3127 installed in a Ubuntu Server virtual machine. I have checked the [link]https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/UpgradingToVOS610 but I cannot find any guidance for updating Virtuoso by Linux command-line. Is there any way I can upgrade Virtuoso this way??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a formula to calculate distance based on Latitudes and Longitudes: http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/haversine/

But, SPARQL does not support trigonometric functions.

GeoSPARQL has the goof:distance function to calculate distance between two geometric points (if you're able to use GeoSPARQL)